# Getting unwanted order when sorting Categorical data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, categorical-data

When sorting columns in a pandas dataframe that contain text (and thus have datatype 'object'), the `df.sort` syntax works, and sorts `apple, orange, banana` in the correct order. However if I convert the fruit column to `Categorical` data type then try and sort it doesn't work.

I want to sort first by a datetime column, and then by a Categorical column, then by some numerical ones (float/int).

Code (where `account` is not categorical) sorts by `month_date` which is datetime object and `account (A-Z)` correctly:

```
#data['month_name'] = pd.Categorical(data['month_name'],
#           categories=data.month_name.unique().tolist())
#data['account'] = pd.Categorical(data['account'],
#           categories=data.account.unique().tolist())

column_list = data.columns.values.tolist()
sorted_data = data.sort(["month_date","account"], ascending=True)
display(sorted_data)
```

Example:

- Apple
- Banana
- Carrot

Code (where `account` is Categorical) does not sort correctly (note pd.categorical data no longer commented out):

```
data['month_name'] = pd.Categorical(data['month_name'],
    categories=data.month_name.unique().tolist())
data['account'] = pd.Categorical(data['account'],
    categories=data.account.unique().tolist())
column_list = data.columns.values.tolist()
sorted_data = data.sort(["month_date","account"], ascending=True)
display(sorted_data)
```

Example

- Apple
- Carrot
- Banana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your categories are themselves not in a guaranteed order. `unique` does not guarantee any order. They will be in the order listed (not clear what the values they have in your example)

```
In [7]: df = DataFrame({'A' : pd.Categorical(list('bbeebbaa'),categories=['e','a','b']), 'B' : np.arange(8) })

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
   A  B
0  b  0
1  b  1
2  e  2
3  e  3
4  b  4
5  b  5
6  a  6
7  a  7

In [9]: df.dtypes
Out[9]: 
A    category
B       int64
dtype: object

In [10]: df.sort(['A','B'])
Out[10]: 
   A  B
2  e  2
3  e  3
6  a  6
7  a  7
0  b  0
1  b  1
4  b  4
5  b  5

In [11]: df.sort(['A','B'],ascending=False)
Out[11]: 
   A  B
5  b  5
4  b  4
1  b  1
0  b  0
7  a  7
6  a  6
3  e  3
2  e  2
```

Comment: I know that unique() does not order the data, it simply gets the unique values in a column. As far as I understand the categories should be in the order defined by my df.sort but they do not appear in that order when I display the dataframe. Month_name which is also categorical doesn't display in the correct order either. I sorted by month_date and expected to see the x axis of my seaborn graph in the order "June","July","Aug", "Sept","Oct" but instead I see August, July, June, October, September.

Comment: the order of the df will be the order of the categories which is in your code done by unique which doesn't have a defined order

Comment: isn't dataframe.sort meant to define the order of the data? my original question was why doesn't that (df.sort) work for categorical data

Comment: does this mean I should only make the "account" column categorical after I have sorted the data in the order that I want? when I test displaying data which has categorical datatype it seems to be displayed in the way it was sorted before the column became categorical.

Comment: categoricals will sort in the order of the categories - so if u want to have a particular ordering (which I can then sort by) u need to put them in that order

Comment: are you saying when I feed a list of categories to the pd.categorical command that list needs to already be in the order that I want the categories to show up in? Does that mean if I do this, the month_name category will also show in the correct order in the bar charts?

Comment: yes, how else would it know how to sort the categories? that is the point of the categories. It IS the sort order.